# subset data from matching package

Tags: r, match, subset, dplyr

So following the example from the Matching package and in particular the GenMatch example [Link to package description](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matching/Matching.pdf) pp11.

We have the following code

```
library(Matching)
data(lalonde)
attach(lalonde)

lalonde$ID <- 1:length(lalonde$age)

X = cbind(age, educ, black, hisp, married, nodegr, u74, u75, re75, re74)

BalanceMat <- cbind(age, educ, black, hisp, married, nodegr, u74, u75, re75, re74,
                    I(re74*re75))

genout <- GenMatch(Tr=treat, X=X, BalanceMatrix=BalanceMat, estimand="ATE", M=1,
                   pop.size=16, max.generations=10, wait.generations=1)

Y=re78/1000

mout <- Match(Y=Y, Tr=treat, X=X, Weight.matrix=genout)
summary(mout)
```

Summary shows us that all 185 `treat==1` cases have been matched

Then we inspect

```
summary(mout$weights)
```

This tells us that some of the `treat==1` cases have been matched multiple times with the `treat==0`

I want to create a data.frame that includes only one occurance of the repeated `treat==1` cases but all the `treat==0`.

So in essence, the length is 185 + `length(mout$index.control)`

Then, I want to introduce a variable `$PairID` which for each `treat==1` case, is repeated for each `treat==0` case.

the data.frame should like:

[image]

So above we see cases 1-3 only return one pair, but case 6 returns 2 pairs. This can be seen by: `mout$weights[mout$index.treated]`

my idea is first remove the repeated $index.treated cases

```
treat <- lalonde[mout$index.treated,]

library(dplyr)

DATA_clean <- treat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(!n() > 1)
```

but this removes all the repeated cases. I want to keep one!

Comment: I don't know dplyr, but maybe there's something like `sample_n(1)` to take a random observation from the group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to keep, say, the first row of `treat` for each value of `ID`, then you can use `slice`:

```
DATA_clean <- treat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(1)
```

Your original code didn't work because `n()` returns to the total number of rows for each value of `ID`. If every `ID` has more than one row, then all of the data gets filtered out. `slice` on the other hand, returns just the rows with the specified indices. If you want one random row, you can replace `slice(1)` with `sample_n(1)` (per @Frank's suggestion).

Comment: thanks for the help I was not familiar with the slice() function